# How to change value of scope within a function - Why is my code not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5

Simple ng-class binding is not triggered when called inside a function, how can I resolve this?

```js
$scope.afterHide = function() {
  $scope.inputState = "fade-in"; 
}
```

```html
<label ng-class="inputState">Next statement</label>
```

Comment: Inside `scope` options `'my-show': '='` should be `'myShow': '='`

Comment: Yes.. there's actually a lot of error with setting up that directive, but its not relevant to my question. 

The actual error is in :

  $scope.afterHide = function() {
      $scope.inputState = "fade-in"; // this line is not called here WHY?
      console.log('Refresh statement fully hidden AFTERHIDE');
    }

Comment: **Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem.** See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine in this example:

```js
angular.module("app",[])

.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.afterHide = function() {
      $scope.inputState = "fade-in"; 
  };
  
  $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.inputState = "";
  };
});
```

```css
.fade-in {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <label ng-class="inputState">Next statement</label>

  <br><button ng-click="afterHide()">Invoke afterHide</button><br>
  <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

---

> If it works then I think it has something to do with the overall logic of my code. The function `$scope.afterHide` is triggered by an event on one of the directives, this directive is defined outside the controller. In html its basically just another div that has a state of change. When a change happens, other elements on the page will also be affected, in this context, that other element is the label tag. When the change happens, the `$scope.afterHide` function within the controller is called by the directive which is defined outside of the controller.

Scopes are arranged in hierarchical structure which mimic the DOM structure of the application.

[image]

The `ng-click` directive cannot invoke a function on a scope that is outside its hierachy. Also if the `ng-click` directive is on a template inside a directive that uses isolate scope, the event must be connected to parent scope with expression, "`&`", binding.

For more infomation, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directives (Isolating a Scope)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)

Comment: Thank you for replying. If it works then I think it has something to do with the overall logic of my code. The function  $scope.afterHide is triggered by an event on one of the directives, this directive is defined outside the controller. In html its basically just another div that has a state of change. When a change happens, other elements on the page will also be affected, in this context, that other element is the label tag. When the change happens, the $scope.afterHide function within the controller is called by the directive which is defined outside of the controller.

Comment: The directive was calling the function, they both had the same controllers but they were out of scope. So I just rearranged the tags in the html file and got it working . I'm trying to give you a point but I don't have enough privilege to do that yet